# Sequence $\ln(n)/n$ to $0$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm taking a real analysis course for my second year and I'm still new when it comes to convergence of a sequence using the M-epsilon definition.

I've simplified my sequence up to
$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n}<\epsilon,$$

but where do I go from here? How do I find an upper bound for $\ln(n)/n$, I have tried using $\epsilon/n$ and $(n-1)/n$ ,but it doesn't satisfy the inequality for a large $n$.

Comment: $$
e^{\sqrt {2n} }  = 1 + \sqrt {2n}  + n +  \frac{(\sqrt{2n})^3}{6}+\cdots  \ge n \Rightarrow \sqrt {2n}  \ge \ln n \Rightarrow \sqrt {\frac{2}{n}}  \ge \frac{{\ln n}}{n}
$$

Comment: Note that a *sequence* and a *series* are not the same thing.

Comment: What's your definition of $\ln$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the hint in the first comment of @Gary we will solve that.
We know that $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!},$$ so we have that
$$n\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{2n})^k}{k!}=e^{\sqrt{2n}}$$
which implies that $$n\leq e^{\sqrt{2n}}$$ so $$\ln(n)\leq\sqrt{2n}$$
and $$\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\leq\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{n}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}.$$
We want $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}<\epsilon$,$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ which are greater than some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$.
So $$\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}<\epsilon$$
$$\iff\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon^2$$
$$\iff n>\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}.$$
If we choose $n_0=\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}+1$ we have that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>n_0$, $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}<\epsilon$, hence our sequence converges to zero by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the integral definition of the natural logarithm. Note that for $n\gt1$ we have

$$\ln n=\int_1^n{dt\over t}=\int_1^\sqrt n{dt\over t}+\int_\sqrt n^n{dt\over t}\lt\int_1^\sqrt n dt+\int_\sqrt n^n{dt\over\sqrt n}\lt\int_0^\sqrt n dt+\int_0^n{dt\over\sqrt n}=\sqrt n+\sqrt n$$

Hence

$$0\lt{\ln n\over n}\lt{2\sqrt n\over n}={2\over\sqrt n}$$

so $\left|\ln n\over n\right|\lt\epsilon$ for all $n\gt4/\epsilon^2$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the maximum of a sequence consider it as a function, namely

$$f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{ x}.$$

Assuming $x>0$ we find the extremum of this function

$$f'(x) = \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}=0 \Rightarrow \ln x =1 \Rightarrow x=e.$$

Then

$$\sup_{x \in [1,\infty)} \frac{\ln x}{x} \leq \frac{1}{e} \Rightarrow | \frac{\ln n}{n}| \leq \frac{1}{e} \quad \forall n > 0 .$$

The second sequence is clear since we have

$$|\frac{1-n}{n}| = |1- \frac{1}{n}| < 1 \quad \forall n > 0$$

Comment: And because of what eventually this sequence converges to 0? Only because the first derivative of this function equals to zero at some point, doesnt mean that at this point the function take its maximum value, it could be the minimum.

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas put $n=1$ you will find the result equals 0 which commit the possibility of being minimum.

Comment: This does not answer the question of why $\ln(n)/n \to 0$. Also, there was no second question. Considering $(n-1)/n$ was just an attempt of the OP to solve the original problem.

Comment: @AliJoony before that mr.Joohy, you say that the supremum of $f(x)$ is less or equal than $\frac{1}{e}$. How do you know what happens for $x\in(0,1)$? You should first look about the monotonicity of the function in order to conclude where its maximum and minimum points are.

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas Yes, you are right. I should have restricted the supremum to $x \in [1,\infty)$.

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas for the second function, i restricted it to $n >1$. However, it is great that you got the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @AliJoohy , your point of view of this problem was also good, you were very close to solve that correctly. You just had to show that at $x_0=e$ the function takes,indeed, its maximum value. For $x<e$, $f'(x)>0$ so $f$ strictly increasing and for $x>e$, $f'(x)<0$ so $f$ strictly decreasing. Thats why max$f$=$\sup_{x\in(0,+\infty)}f(x)=f(e)=1/e$